# How do I extract a string value from a cell so I can check its datatype? Intro Matlab Q

Tags: string, matlab, cell

Part of my assignment is testing what datatype is stored in my "studentNames" variable.

However I believe that because the `studentNames` are being held within a cell that **MATLAB** cant detect the datatype.

How could I solve this problem?

Editor Window

```
function [studentCell] =classCellArray(studentNames, studentIDs, studentGrades)

studentCell(1,:) = [ **studentNames{1,:}** studentIDs(1,:) studentGrades(1,:) {mean(studentGrades(1,:))}]; 
studentCell(2,:) = [ studentNames{2,:} studentIDs(2,:) studentGrades(2,:) {mean(studentGrades(2,:))}];
studentCell(3,:) = [ studentNames{3,:} studentIDs(3,:) studentGrades(3,:) {mean(studentGrades(3,:))}];
studentCell(4,:) = [ studentNames{4,:} studentIDs(4,:) studentGrades(4,:) {mean(studentGrades(4,:))}];
```

Command window

```
studentCell = 

'Ali'    'G10293'    [1x3 double]    [82.6667]
'Yin'    'G10498'    [1x3 double]    [     93]
'Bob'    'G10201'    [1x3 double]    [56.6667]
'Jim'    'G19532'    [1x3 double]    [    100]
```

EDU>> class(studentNames)
**Error using subsindex**
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.**

Comment: First off, you are calling `function` incorrectly. And you can find out classes by either `class(studentCell)`, or `whos studentCell`. To find out the class within a cell structure, simply call `class(studentCell{1})`

Comment: Thanks for your response Gaurav, however my Professor is going to check my code by typing whats below. Can I inlcude something in my code that would allow any user to find out the class of my data types? Thanks                                                                                       >> class(studentNames)
ans =
char